# Can I disable sticky keys through a Group Policy for all users?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, group-policy, rdp, terminal-server

Our users are constantly managing to turn sticky keys on and then call tech support because their keys are bring up windows instead of typing letters.

Is there a way to disable StickyKeys in Group Policy? I tried disabling it on the server itself, but the problem still occurs so I think it must be something set at the user-profile level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the following registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys\Flags="506"`

There is also a custom template that someone designed [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/is/winserverGP/thread/6ba301df-5e3a-49ce-900a-c6b8c20217f3)